# How can a template function 'know' the size of the array given as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

In the C++ code below, the templated Check function gives an output that is not what I would like: it's 1 instead of 3. I suspect that K is mapped to `int*`, not to `int[3]` (is that a type?).  I would like it to give me the same output than the second (non templated) function, to which I explicitly give the size of the array...

Short of using macros, is there a way to write a Check function that accepts a single argument but still knows the size of the array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int data[] = {1,2,3};

template <class K>
void Check(K data) {
  cout << "Deduced size: " << sizeof(data)/sizeof(int) << endl;
}

void Check(int*, int sizeofData) {
  cout << "Correct size: " << sizeofData/sizeof(int) << endl;
}

int main() {
  Check(data);
  Check(data, sizeof(data));
}
```

Thanks.

PS: In the real code, the array is an array of structs that must be iterated upon for unit tests.

Comment: Better to use a std::vector instead of an array.

Comment: In your original code, the type `K` degenerates to a pointer when you pass an array to `Check`. This is normal C/C++ behavior, with or without templates involved. Fortunately, C++ provides a mechanism to preserve the array size, by using an integral constant as a template parameter. See Alexey Malistov's answer for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template<class T, size_t S> 
void Check(T (&)[S]) {  
   cout << "Deduced size: " << S << endl;
}
```

Comment: can you explain it please?