# Get the type and size of a template variable

Tags: c++

```
template<class TYPE>
void execute(TYPE data)
{
    int size = sizeof(data)*sizeof(TYPE);
}
```

The above returns wrong result.

I am calling the template like this:

```
execute(&variable);
```

The variable can be any type, **but will always be array.**

I expect the code to return size as **(the number of elements in array)*(the size of the variable type)**

For example, if I have an array of floats with 2 elements, I want to return 2*4 = 8;

Comment: Are you looking for `template <int num_elems> class foo { ... }`? Or in what sense does "the above return wrong result"?

Comment: `sizeof(data)` and `sizeof(TYPE)` will return the same value in your example above, giving you `sizeof(TYPE)` squared.  I doubt that's useful.  You need a way to get "number of elements" into your computation.

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: Check out this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873773/how-can-a-template-function-know-the-size-of-the-array-given-as-template-argum?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be more useful to make the template accept arrays directly:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void execute(T (&data)[N])
{
    // array size is N
}
```

Usage:

```
double x[3] = {};

execute(x);
```

You don't even need a separate variable for the array size; it's directly available as the template parameter `N`.

Comment: A bit confused... On my template I called the array data. Here, how the array is called?

Comment: @SkyRipper: Fixed, now it's called `data`, too.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without passing the array, because it will be very big and will take time to be copied?

Comment: @SkyRipper: It's passed by reference. No copying happens. You cannot pass arrays by value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is usual for you to compute the size of objects in bytes you are probably doing something wrong!

From the looks of it you want to compute the size of an array. If that's the case you'll need to pass the array by reference as it will decay into a pointer when pass by value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t size_of(T const&) {
    return sizeof(T);
}
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t size(T(&)[Size]) {
    return Size;
}

int main() {
    int array[5];
    std::cout << "size=" << size(array) << '/' << size_of(array) << '\n';
}
```

The code determines both the number of elements (what is typically quite useful) and the size in `char`s of the object. The number of elements can only be determined for arrays while they size in `char`s should work with all objects.

Comment: My compiler (MSVC 2012) doesn't understand constexpr?

Comment: @SkyRipper: You can remove `constexpr`: you can get the values as run-time values but not as constant expressions without `constexpr`. That is, you can't use, e.g., `char buffer[size_of(array)]` (if you want to do that without `constexpr` you'll need to use `sizeof()` with a function returning a reference of an array of `char` of the appropriate size).

Comment: thanks, i will try it. c++11 is hard. cuda is hard. i am a beginner... i guess i will have a hard time... :/